# Proper way to remove or dismiss ViewControllers reached by segue

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, interface-builder, segue

I am using storyboard segues to move from one screen to another in my iPhone app. The forward segues A --> B --> C are currently modal segues, performed as follows in code (A to B, where B is the previewController):

```
-(void) prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue*)segue sender:(id)sender
{
   if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"previewSegue"])
    preview = (previewController*)segue.destinationViewController;
    preview.player = self.player;
    preview.opponent = self.opponent;
   }
 }
```

And I call the segue

```
[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"previewSegue" sender:nil];
```

I used Interface Builder to draw out the segue and, for no particular reason, chose it to be modal (the other choice was push).  The transition works fine, so I used the same logic to move from B to C.  When the review screen (call it screen C) is done, I drew a segue on the storyboard back to the exit icon above C's layout, and implemented unwind in viewControllerA:

```
-(IBAction) unwindToViewController: (UIStoryboardSegue*)sender
{
UIViewController* sourceViewController = sender.sourceViewController;

if ([sourceViewController isKindOfClass:[reviewController class]]) // <--- this is C
{
    NSLog(@"Coming from REVIEW CONTROLLER!");

    // Dismiss everything related to C
    if (preview != nil) {
        [preview dismissC];
        preview = nil;
    }
}
}
```

And the dismissC function I wrote in B is the following:

```
- (IBAction) dismissC
{
NSLog(@"C dismissal called!");

// Release data so nothing points to it any longer, and it can go out of scope
if (reviewController != nil)
    reviewController = nil;  // <----reviewController points to C during segue B --> C

}
```

My problem is that C is still hanging around in the program after I unwound back to A.  I know this because C instantiates some AVAudioPlayers that are playing music and sound effects during C's presentation.  During the exit code of C, I make sure to stop all of these audio players, invalidate timers, set the vars to nil, etc. But if I exit C, even though the music stops playing, I still hear delayed effects resulting from the user having touched things in C.  For example, there's a button that plays a press noise in C a few secs after being touched, and continually thereafter in an echo, and it still plays after C has unwound to A, and presumably been dismissed.

How do I properly rid all memory of C?  Sure, the user may go back to C via segue A-->B-->C, but then I want to allocate new B and new C at that point, without all these residual noises hanging around.  I think I must be doing something wrong with these segues and unwinds, because once I'm back at A, I'm pretty sure all traces of C should be gone, even delayed noises.

EDIT FOR CONTEXT: A is a normal ViewController with a collection view that the user scrolls to browse a bunch of videos/thumbnails of albums. When user selects one, A passes the selected title to B, which is a time-limited "preview" of the video, during which advertisements play, and user can choose to purchase & see more, or go back to A.  When timer runs out, B segues to C, which is another timed view controller with various buttons that do things to the full video playing, such as muting, adding sounds, recording commentary, etc. When the timer on C runs out, I want the program to go back to A and get rid of (release) all the data from B and C, so that when another title is chosen, B starts afresh.  The current behavior is a problem because some of the sounds and audio players that I stopped right before calling ReviewController's (C) segue to exit play in the background even after the user has returned to A.  The video and other elements of C are no longer visible, or crash the program, but the sounds from the stopped AudioPlayers continue to activate, and I can't trace them in the debugger or anything, so I have no idea who is pointing to them, why they're not released, etc.  The AVAudioPlayers in C are declared (nonatomic, strong) properties, which I can change if this produces the undesired behavior.

Comment: First name you classes with capital letter at the beginning. Aren't you messing them with variable names?

Comment: Re: Cy-4AH, thanks for your concern. I named all my classes with capital letters, but in my code above, things like "reviewController" and "previewController" are variables, and their classes are ReviewController and PreviewController.  The reason you don't see the declarations is because they are internal variables I defined inside curly braces under @implementation, as a way to pass data between the view controllers during the segue.

Answer (score 1):

I think, when you would like to dismiss "C", the best option is use:

```
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
```

With this, you don't need a "go back" segue, just the "C" view is dismissed and "B" view is show.

And, if you need to stop or release something about the audio player (or whatever you want), you can use the "completion" block.

I hope this help you!

Comment: I actually had a question pertaining to this subject. If her AVAudioPlayers have a weak reference, would that also release them once `ViewControllerC` is dismissed?

Comment: If you have a weak reference, I think this will not release it. But I'm not sure.

Comment: Thanks! Re: kemmitorz, is there any way to dismiss "B" at the same time so it doesn't show up?  B is really just a preview of C, so when user quits out of C, B needs to disappear, too.   Re: Fabian Good point: My AVAudioPlayers have a strong reference, not sure if I need to release them. Beyond calling [player stop], is there anything else I can do? I don't think it is wise to call [player release] because ARC should handle that?

Comment: This didn't work. I tried dismissing ViewControllerC from both itself and ViewControllerB, and made all my references to both ViewControllers __weak in front.  The sounds still continue to play, and alerts generated by ViewControllerC still continue to appear :(

Answer (score 0):

I can't guarantee that this code work, because you make have memory leaks in other places.
But I think your's code should look like that:

```
-(IBAction) unwindToViewController: (UIStoryboardSegue*)sender
{
    if (preview == sender.sourceViewController)
    {
        NSLog(@"Coming from REVIEW CONTROLLER!");
        preview = nil;
    }
}
```

Comment: The code didn't work, as the sounds continue to play, and alertViews generated by ViewControllerC continue to appear.  When you say "memory leaks" where exactly could such a thing occur?  I already made all my VC references __weak, and I'm using ARC.  I ran a search through my code, and the ViewControllerC instance is never shared or kept around outside that one __weak pointer from ViewControllerB. I would think that having only one reference, which is later dismissed and set to nil, would be enough? Is there a way to explicitly get rid of something when you KNOW it's the only reference to it?